# For a React app theme, is there an advantage of material-ui makeStyles vs. SCSS architecture?

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I just joined a team developing a React app. We are currently relying on Material UI, including `makeStyles`, to style the app. One of my tasks is going to be to suss out our global theme. In my tradition, I've relied on LESS and SCSS to implement app styling and theme architecture.

Is there an advantage to sticking with Material UI `makeStyles` (aside from the fact that it has already been implemented) over switching up theme architecture to use SCSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `makeStyles` is a great way to use a theme based UI. It allows you to use commom properties and methods to generate style based configured variables.

Hook usage with theme:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme:MyCustomTheme)=>{
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: theme.myBorder,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: theme.shaodws.boxShadowPrimary,
    color: theme.colors.primary,
    height: theme.size(1),
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function MyCustomThemeButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Also you can provide custom props when implementing the hook:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme:MyCustomTheme)=>{
  root: (props) => ({
    border: props.hasBorder ? theme.myBorder : 'none',
    color: props.textColor || theme.color.text.pirmary
  })
});

export default function MyCustomThemeButton(props) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles({
    hasBorder: props.isOutsideBox,
    textColor: active ? "red" : "yellow"
  });
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

To read more on the topic: [Material UI styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it gives a specific use case for when mui is more advantageous, i.e. theme-based UI. Right on! Makes sense to me. Thanks also for these helpful examples of how to fully take advantage of mui.

Answer (score 2):

I use both makeStyles and scss pretty interchangeably.

However, I would avoid mixing them at the component level... that could be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison Bobby, I appreciate you explaining how you combine these tools.